# How to remove nodes from Views in drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

My view holds a list of nodes ranked by rating (vote-API/Fivestar).

I wish user to hide nodes they do not wish to see in this view. Can this be done?

Comment: This can be done in a number of ways. Do you want the user to select nodes to hide, or do you want certain nodes to be hidden from all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag). Users flag content (nodes), then you hide it using view filters.

Comment: I wouldn't do that: flag storage tends to be more costly in terms of DB queries than taxonomy, for cases like this one.

Comment: taxonomy it's not enough because you have to store who marked what.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really lazy (and future-proof), use taxonomy.

Create a vocabulary called "Visible" and add a "No" term.

Then filter out all the nodes tagged with Visible/No with views.

Always better to use plain language with newb users anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is it completely arbitrary which nodes they don't want to see? Like they just want to hide an single node they already read on don't care about? If so then there is no easy way that I know of. That would require some sort of custom module that I've never come across.

If it is more predictable and consistent like the user wanting to change the view to only show nodes that are rated 3 or above or 4 or above then you can do that by creating a filter for and exposing it.

Hope that helps.